# How to change add media button in moodle tinymce editor?

Tags: tinymce, moodle

I've been learning Moodle CMS and I'm stuck in one problem. I'm using tinymce as a default editor. There's insert video button but popup window doesn't have full functionality as an original tinymce insert video popup window.
[image]

How can I change it? I want to choose HTML5 from Type and control the Dimensions of the video. But now it's not possible in Moodle Tinymce Editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of searching google, I came to an answer on the [moodle forum](https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=225806)

Here's what I did to use original tinymce media insert:
1) Adding media plugin to the config file: `lib/editor/tinymce/lib.php`

```
'plugins' => 'safari,...,media',
```

2) From moodle admin settings of tinymce editor, add media button.